# Locate and Rename column header containing unprintable characters in R

Tags: r

I have tables with one or more columns containing unprintable characters as column name as shown below (in the second and fifth column). These columns occur at random positions in the tables. I am not able to locate these columns through R code to rename it by column position.  Please advise.

```
>test <- structure(list(AA = 1:3, X... = c(23L, 55L, 33L), 
                BB = c(10, 20, 30), 
                CC = structure(1:3, .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), 
                class = "factor"), ï.. = c(12L, 34L, 534L)), 
                .Names = c("AA", "ï..", "BB", "CC", "ï.."), 
               class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))
> test
  AA ï.. BB CC ï..
1  1  23 10  a  12
2  2  55 20  b  34
3  3  33 30  c 534
```

Comment: It is better to use `dput` to show the data.  Perhaps `i1 <- grepl("![[:ascii:]]+", names(data), perl = TRUE); names(data)[i1] <- replacementvector`

Comment: A code example will help. Use `dput(head(my_object))` if copy paste doesn't help.

Comment: You can locate with `names(test)[grepl('ï', names(test))]`. I used the first special character to search for. You can customize based on results.

Comment: Try with `grepl("[[:cntrl:]]", stringi::stri_enc_toascii(names(test)))#
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE` as showed in the dupe link

Comment: @akrun, Thanks. I somehow missed the earlier entry on "detecting non ascii characters in a string" in this forum. Should I delete this question?

Comment: @PierreLafortune, the challenge is the special character is not always the same. I missed to mention this in my query.

Comment: No, you don't have to delete it.  In fact, dupe questions makes it easier to search on google